# Unable to access layout inflater as child view has not initialised

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Android activity that searches a web service for new content to display then either displays a NoResultFragment or a ResultFragment which represents a swipe stack for the user to swipe through the items returned. Because I need to manage the stack, retrieving more data in the background as the stack gets low etc from the Activity, all of the stack details are held at the activity level and the yes/no actions trigger methods on the activity. All good so far.

The problem is I am using the layout inflater in the ResultFragment class to generate dynamic child Views, each one of which represents an item on the stack. These then get returned to the Activity controller which manages them, sends them to the fragment to display, hides them, moves them around etc, so I need access to the child item Views from the activity to do all this. I need to generate the actual child views from within the ResultFragment though, as that is where they will be visually displayed.

I create the ResultFragment, set it to the content area and then try and generate the child views by calling into the fragment created. The error is that the onViewCreate() method has not yet been called on the ResultFragment class as it has only just been added to the content frame, so there is no layoutinflater and my method to return the child View fails. I get the feeling there is something off with my design here, can someone shed some light on how to do this? Is it as simple as just passing through the parent layoutinflater from the Activity class?

Child view creation method

```
public View getChildView(StorySeed seed, int seedIndex)
    {
        final View m_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, null);                    // Code to populate the view
                      return m_view;
}
```

activity method

```
private void initialiseResults(ArrayList<StorySeed> storySeeds) {
        resultsFragment = new ResultsFragment(storySeeds, getApplicationContext());
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, resultsFragment)
                .commit();

        // load the first results to screen 
        seedIndex = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < seedsToDisplay; i++) {          
            getNextToStack();           
        }                       
    }
```

It is the call to getNextToStack() that is going into the Fragment class and calling the getChildView() method

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the way you're interacting between the Activity and the Fragment.  Rather than have the Fragment create views and return them to the Activity so it can turn them back around to the Fragment to be added to the layout, consider having the Activity dictate to the Fragment (via arguments) what "mode" it should be in which dictates the views and layout.  If your Fragment is managing complex and changing layouts then consider breaking it down into separate Fragments instead of doing everything in one class.

Comment: Thats how I originally designed it. The difficulty I had is that I wanted to switch to different fragments for "Loading" mode, "No results mode" and "Results found" mode. But as the triggers from all of this would come from within the ResultsFragment, I didn't see how to get the ResultsFragment to tell the application to replace itself with a different fragment, I thought I would have to do that from the activity. Is there a way I can change the content of the activities frame to a different fragment, from within the REsultFragment?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that from a Fragment directly.  Instead, have your ResultFragment define an inner interface called ResultCallback which your Activity implements.  In your ResultFragment's `onAttach`, check to ensure that the provided Activity is an instance of your interface (throw an exception if not).  Then when you need to "switch" the fragment, just have ResultFragment call the "registered" interface notifying it of the change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create the views in the activity (the controller) and pass them to the fragment as needed. The fragment is your MVC "view" and it should only tell the controller what happened. The controller decides what to do after that.

The way you can have one fragment replace itself by another is to call a method on the activity. Here's a quick example:

```
interface IAppController {
    void onResultsNotFound();
}

class MyActivity extends Activity implements IAppController{
    ....
    public void onResultNotFound(){
        //switch fragments
    }
}

class MyFragment {
    ....
    void myMethod(){
        IAppController controller = (IAppController) getActivity();
        controller.onResultsNotFound();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps